# how to prove this change of order of summation and integration

Tags: integration, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

the step I got stuck is:
\begin{equation} \int\limits_0^{\infty}\sum_{y>x}\mathcal{p_\mathit{X}}(y)\,dx=\sum_{y>0}(\int\limits_0^y \mathcal{p_\mathit{X}}(y)\,dx) \end{equation}
the context is,  $\mathcal{p_\mathit{X}}(y)$ is a probability mass function here. I know it's kind of like reversing the order of integration in the continuous case, but I can't prove it in detail.

Comment: Do you know Tonelli's theorem?

Comment: @jakobdt no, I don't. I've only learned some elementary calculus yet and know little about higher order math like measure theory. The probability textbook where I found this problem is also just an introduction not based on measure theory.

Comment: Ok. I wrote an answer which uses the monotone convergence theorem instead. Even if you don't know it, it should be easy enough to understand the statement of the theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in(0,\infty)$ you have that $\sum_{y=1}^n 1_{\{y>x\}}p_X(y)\uparrow\sum_{y=1}^\infty 1_{\{y>x\}}p_X(y)$ for $n\to\infty$. Then, by the monotone convergence theorem, we find that
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\sum_{y>x}p_X(y)\,\mathrm{d}x&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{y=1}^\infty 1_{\{y>x\}}p_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\sum_{y=1}^n 1_{\{y>x\}}p_X(y)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{y=1}^n\int_0^\infty 1_{\{y>x\}}p_X(y)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\sum_{y=1}^\infty \int_0^y p_X(y)\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
$$